# how do I declare const variables in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, constants

I would like to be a better code.. making my code cleaner and more readable.

One thing I've seen in c/c++ is the use of const on local variables. I think there is a lot of value in telling the reader of my code that once the variable is set, it is not changed in the function/method.

I'm wondering.... is there a way to indicate a local variable is const?

```
#for example 
sql = "select * from table1 where status = #{iStatusId}"
connection.execute(sql)
```

sql will not change in this method.  Can I mark it so?

Ok.. that's a bad example, but I think the point is made... I hope :)

EDIT:
I added a bit of dynamic to the sql.. the iStatusId bit is a parameter passed into the method.

EDIT2:
I did google this...  all articles talk of magic number replacement.  That's a no brainer and what I'd consider a MACRO.  CONTANTS are easy... I'm looking for const..   they are very different things.

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Comment: If methods are appropriately-sized it'll be obvious from inspection. While I have *some* sympathy towards the goal, IMO many other things are significantly more important.

Comment: totally googled it @rudolph9.   No mention of consts that leads me to believe they setable.  I'm not looking to replace magic numbers, I'm looking to create constant variables.  ERROR = dynamic constant assignment

Comment: You know you have an SQL injection there?

Comment: @Tass  tis a simple example :  not production, just to express my query.  :)

Comment: @daveatflow Like method size, class size, naming, using canonical style, formatting, proper class design, etc. Indicating that a string won't change barely makes my list.

Comment: @DaveNewton tis an example made simple to express the idea.  I don't want to indicate that a string won't change.. I want to make it so the variable can't be changed.  Be that an int or what have you. In c you don't indicate a variable won't change, you make it bloody hard to change it.

Comment: @daveatflow Tough to make a constant in Ruby, and inside a method, IMO it's worthless.

Comment: @DaveNewton cool.. but they have em in c#, java, c, c++, vb.. seems the paradigm is almost omnipresent.  There must be value.  I think though I see why they're not in Ruby... most everything is a pointer (behind the scenes) const pointers aren't really logical.

Comment: @daveatflow "They're there, they must have value." Dangerous thinking, AFAIC. Your reasoning as to why they don't exist is flawed; Java could skip primitives and have only references and still have finals. Again: inside a method indicating a value won't change has very little value, *IMO*. For something like a configuration value, default value, etc. they *do* have value--but in Ruby they're only barely "constant".

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy enough to cook up the logic you are describing, by using something like this:

```
class Thing

    def unchangeable_attribute
      @unchangeable_attribute
    end

    def unchangeable_attribute=(value)
      raise SomeError if @unchangeable_attribute
      @unchangeable_attribute = value
    end

end
```

I tend to agree with Dave Newton, though, as I have a hard time imagining a great use case for something like this...

Comment: in other languages, consts are compiled to smaller and faster code. They make it harder for others using your variables to mess em up, which given most of my co-workers are "young" helps me ooot.

Comment: Right... That's what this does too, with the probable exception of "compiled to smaller and faster code". There are probably better ways to accomplish what you are trying to achieve, like a robust test suite, for example, but this makes the attribute settable exactly one time only.

Comment: Oh even better link.. PS THANKS BRAD.. really thanks... and thanks to DAVE too.. http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm

Comment: FWIW,I'm not really interested in the "worth it or not" debate - if you have a legit use case, do what you need, but it really seems like you're trying to write c (or something) in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

What about the `obj.freeze` method defined on Ruby objects? From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze):

> Prevents further modifications to obj. A RuntimeError will be raised if modification is attempted. There is no way to unfreeze a frozen object.

Answer (score -1):

Constants just begin with a capital letter, so the following will work just fine:

```
MY_CONSTANT = 1234
```

However, overwriting a constant is possible, although it will issue a warning.

Answer (score -2):

Const's in ruby aren't strictly logical.  As "all" variables are really just masked pointers to objects, casting them to the c paradigm of const doesn't make sense.

It would be equal to 
const void * value = 'bla';

You could still change value[1].

I'd love to be proven wrong here.